# How to bring back a Docker Container exited with 0

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, containers, docker-registry

I currently have a docker container installed on devices, however, some devices have their docker application container exited with `0`, and doing a `docker start container ID`, the container will start for a few seconds and then exit with `0` again.

Commands like `docker logs` won't work because container is not running. Using `docker inspect` looks okay, as a good running container.

I'm just trying to bring the exited container back to running. But nothing seems to bring it back. Also, commands like `systemctl --failed` show good results. Is there a way to force the container to not exit with code `0`, or where else could I debug the container to see why it exited with code `0`?

Comment: `docker logs` should work as long as the container *exists*, meaning they're removed then the container is *removed*

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] or any relevant source code?  That message just says "the main container process completed successfully", which could be caused by a very wide range of things (some intentional).  I'd recommend `docker rm` the stopped container once you've extracted its logs and then `docker run` a new one, so you're sure it's in a clean environment.

Answer (score 1):

`docker logs` works even for non running containers and usually gives good hints about what happened.

You can call it with container ID or container name, e.g., when you have a container named `pgadmin` you could do `docker logs pgadmin`.

`docker container ls -a` will give you a list of all containers, even those not running.

Exit code `0` usually indicates that the container did not stop because of an error. It could also be a problem of the image you are using. Did you create the image yourself?